# SQL - Filter duplicate rows with different values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I come across an issue where it needs to filter out duplicate rows while restricting some criteria on another column, for example, filter out rows duplicated by `MappingID` and `Date` columns, but **must have both** NULL and NOT NULL value for `Subject` column.

Original data:

```
| Subject      | MappingID | Date       | Qty    | 
+--------------+-----------+------------+--------+
| NULL         | M1        | 2020-11-01 |  10    | 
| S1           | M1        | 2020-11-01 |  20    | 
| S2           | M2        | 2020-11-01 |   5    |
| S2           | M2        | 2020-11-01 |   6    |
| NULL         | M1        | 2020-11-02 |   7    |
```

Expected result (`Subject` is pivoted, `M2` is not included in the result set because Subject is the same) :

```
| MappingID | Date       | Subject1 | Subject2 | Subject1Qty | Subject2Qty |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| M1        | 2020-11-01 | S1       | NULL     |     20      |     10      |
```

Comment: You can't pivot arbitrarily in T-SQL: you need to predefine pivoted column names. But it's even better to not pivot at all. Do you absolutely have to pivot the result data?

Comment: Can a `mapping_id` have more than two subjects on the same `day`, such as `NULL, S1, S2`? If so, what are the limits, and what are your expected results for such a scenario?

Comment: Can a `mapping_id` have multiple rows for the same subject on the same `day`, and still meet your other criteria? Such as `NULL, NULL, S1, S1`? If so, what are your expected results for such a scenario?

Comment: @Dai I need to compare those NULL and NOT NULL Subject, do you have any other suggestions if not using pivot?

Comment: @MatBailie, Yes, there may be more than two subjects, for  those not null subjects, we can combine them as one

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select mappingid, date,
    max(case when rn = 1 then subject end) as subject1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then subject end) as subject2,
    max(case when rn = 1 then qty     end) as qty1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then qty     end) as qty2
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by mappingid, date order by subject) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by mappingid, date
having max(subject) is not null 
   and max(case when subject is null then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without a subquery -- assuming you have two rows per id and date:

```
select mappingid, date,
       max(subject) as subject_1,
       max(case when subject is not null then qty end) as qty_1,
       null as subject_2,
       max(case when subject is null then qty end) as qty_2
from t
group by mappingid, date
having count(subject) = 1 and count(*) = 2;
```